# Can an enemy missed by Bard's Compulsion still charge?

Tags: dnd-4e, bard, charge

From the Bard's 5th level Daily power:

> **Miss:** ...and it cannot take move actions on its next turn.

Can an enemy affected by this power still charge on its turn?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Yes**,

Charge <sup>[DDI](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/glossary.aspx?id=324)</sup> is not a move action, it is a standard action that allows you to move your speed and then attack.

Comment: Correct. Would the power say _"... and it cannot move on its next turn."_ then the affected enemy cannot charge (because charge requires a move).